# Which one is the most optimal way to delete and update query in mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database, optimization

Suppose, I need to delete or update some id informations from my database, which would be the best way to do it? Should I first find out that if that id exists or not? Or should I update the data then check the result if that comes false that means that data doesn't exist.

**method 1**

```
let find_id = "Select id from MyGuests where id=2";
if(find_id.length === 0 || find_id.length === undefined) {
      return not found //immediately exit
   }
let result = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2"
return result;
```

or should I use this one?

**method 2**

```
let result = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2"
 if (result === 0) {
        return not found
    }
return result;
```

Same question is for my delete query also? Which one is the optimal way?

Comment: You're never executing the queries. You're just testing the length of a string.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get your answer @Barmar, Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: `let find_id = "Select id from MyGuests where id=2";` sets `find_id` to a string, it doesn't ever query the database.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213397/is-it-worth-checking-value-with-select-before-updating

Comment: @GordonLinoff What are you referring to? Where does it check whether a database exists. It's just checking whether the row to be updated exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's best to minimize the number of queries sent to the database. So you should just perform the `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. Then you can check the `affectedRows` count in the result.

```
var sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2";
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.affectedRows == 0) {
        console.log("ID not found");
    }
});
```

Don't forget that database queries are asynchronous, you can't return a result in the normal way. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)